# XSD: ComplexType

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb

I have a complexType like:

```
<xsd:complexType name="NightlyRate">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="com:Money">
            <xsd:attribute name="night" type="com:Number" use="required"/>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Now, I want to add a child element to "NightlyRate", which itself is of complexType. I tried adding:

```
<xsd:element name="xxx" type"com:Money"/>
```

after the complexContent element, but it throws error that element is not expected, also part of the problem is type of this complex-element is the same as type of extension base. I am using JAXB. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Would adding mixed="true" in ComplexContent help?

Comment: Adding mixed=true helps, if your NightlyRate contains textual contents along with the elements you want to define.

Answer (score 2):

To get sub-elements in a `xsd:complexType`, you have to put a `xsd:sequence` in it (first level, along with annotations and attributes), wich states that you want well... sub-elements. In this sequence, you can include elements of other defined types or define new types.

See [XSD complex elements at W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex.asp), and womp's example.

In some cases, you may want to use the `xsd:any` element to allow yet-undefined extensions (loose).

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsd:complexType name="NightlyRate">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="com:Money">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="xxx" type"com:Money">
                   <xsd:complexType>
                      <xsd:complexContent>
                             /// Attributes here
                      </xsd:complexContent>
                   </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>

            <xsd:attribute name="night" type="com:Number" use="required"/>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Some explanation here would probably be helpful.

Comment: It throws following error:

"The content type of a derived type and that of its base must both be mixed or both be element-only. Type 'NightlyRate' is element only, but its base type is not."

Comment: Ankush, that error means that your "xxx" element must also be a complexType.  I assume that it is, and that you would have attributes for it.  If it's not, and it's just a straight reference to another element type defined elsewhere, change it to <xsd:element ref="xxx" />, where xxx is the name of the element.

Comment: Hi Womp, Thanks for the code example n explanation, that made it so much clear. But, I still have a question...my "xxx" type is complexType, as I am saying its attribute type is com:Money, which itself is complexType in my schema. But, I don't really need to extend or add any attributes to it. So, shouldn't just saying the name of the element and its type suffice?, and if does, then why am I still getting this error?

Comment: have you already declared <xsd:element name="xxx" /> somewhere else in your schema?  if so, you can just use <xsd:element ref="xxx" /> instead of declaring a new element. 
if you haven't declared it somewhere else already, and it has no properties, consider making it an attribute of NightlyRate instead of an element.